# royal icing and candy atop buttercream

Tags: cake

Can I put royal icing snowflakes and hard candy shards on top of buttercream icing one day ahead or will the buttercream dissolve the royal icing and hard candy?

Comment: I am not familiar with royal icing, but the hard candy should be fine.  It might bleed slightly into the icing immediately touching it but that shouldn't even be noticeable.

Comment: isn't royal icing just water and powdered sugar? I don't see a problem especially if you store it at a cool temperature.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be fine. I had some buttercream frosting left over from answering a [previous question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/56605/1549) and did a simple test not long after you asked this question (about 16 hours ago).

I put a dish of frosting into the fridge with small royal icing and sugar/starch based decorations on top and I left a similar dish at room temperature. I pushed the decorations firmly into the frosting.

The decorations retained pretty much all their crunch. They didn't leak any of their bright coloring into the frosting either; not that that would be a problem if you're decorations are snowflakes. I'm not sure whether the opposite would be a problem, i.e. if your frosting is brightly colored and your decorations are white.

You can judge for yourself whether the ingredient proportions I tested with are comparable to yours by checking the answer I linked to above. You may see different results if the proportion of wet ingredients in your recipe is much larger.